# How to use ffmpeg for streaming

Tags: ffmpeg

I streamed image with audio like

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -re -framerate 1 -i "test.jpg" -thread_queue_size 512 -i "test.mp3" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -r 1 -g 2 -b:v 150k -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -bufsize 256k -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320x180,setsar=1:1 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxx
```

Now, I need to stream video and audio using ffmpeg. How to do it? I need minimum bitrate and framerate possible. I tried like `ffmpeg -nostdin -re -thread_queue_size 6512 -i "output2.mp4" -i "output2.mp3" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

I get error like

> av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipeB time=00:01:02.42 bitrate=5279.0kbits/s speed=   1x
> [flv @ 0x345345] Failed to update header with correct duration.
> [flv @ 0x345345] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
> Error writing trailer of rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxx

Also tried `ffmpeg -nostdin -re -thread_queue_size 9512 -i "output2.mp4" -i "output2.mp3" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -r 25 -b:v 2150k -c:a aac -ar 44100 -bufsize 9256k  -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxxxx`. Another error returns

> av_interleaved_write_frame(): End of fileB time=00:00:10.03 bitrate=2330.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1370 speed=0.161x
> [flv @ 0x5562b] Failed to update header with correct duration.
> [flv @ 0x5562b] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
> Error writing trailer of rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx

Comment: What research have you done and what else have you tried? Where is your video coming from?

Comment: I've updated my question. The file is in local folder.

Comment: According the [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723571/correct-usage-of-thread-queue-size-in-ffmpeg) `-thread_queue_size` should be set before each `-i`. The error message is strange. What version of FFmpeg are you using?